# Are there programming languages designed to use only speech for input?

Tags: programming-languages

I am interested in developing a domain-specific language which could be driven only by speech input. Are there examples of programming languages designed specifically for speech-only input? We can assume some form of feedback and storage (for humans), probably a screen although I'd also be interested in languages which have no feedback. I'd be interested in both formal grammars and natural language input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perligata is highly pronounceable (http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Perligata.html)

```
 use Lingua::Romana::Perligata;

    maximum inquementum tum biguttam egresso scribe.
    meo maximo vestibulo perlegamentum da.
    da duo tum maximum conscribementa meis listis.

    dum listis decapitamentum damentum nexto
    fac sic
            nextum tum novumversum scribe egresso.
            lista sic hoc recidementum nextum cis vannementa da listis.
    cis.
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but I'll accept it as the best offered and maybe useful to others.

Answer (score 4):

[LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE) :)

```
HAI
CAN HAS STDIO?
I HAS A VAR
IM IN YR LOOP
   UP VAR!!1
   IZ VAR BIGGER THAN 10? KTHX
   VISIBLE VAR
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
KTHXBYE
```

---

Might be releated: [Is There a Human Readable Programming Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202750/is-there-a-human-readable-programming-language)

Comment: +1 looks promising. The vocabulary should be fairly easy for a speech-recognition tool. Are line-ends significant? I assume not